# Swift Decodable Optional Key

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

*(This is a follow-up from this question: [Using Decodable protocol with multiples keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46723619/819340).)*

I have the following Swift code:

```
let additionalInfo = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: UserInfoKeys.self, forKey: .age)
age = try additionalInfo.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .realage)
```

I know that if I use `decodeIfPresent` and don't have the property it will still handle it correctly if it's an optional variable.

For example the following JSON works to parse it using the code above.

```
{
    "firstname": "Test",
    "lastname": "User",
    "age": {"realage": 29}
}
```

And the following JSON works as well.

```
{
    "firstname": "Test",
    "lastname": "User",
    "age": {"notrealage": 30}
}
```

But the following doesn't work.

```
{
    "firstname": "Test",
    "lastname": "User"
}
```

How can I make all 3 examples work? Is there something similar to `decodeIfPresent` for `nestedContainer`?

Comment: for every one trying to achieve these kind of requirements, You can use this pod https://github.com/muhammadali2012/Model

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use the following [`KeyedDecodingContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2893337-contains) function:

```
func contains(_ key: KeyedDecodingContainer.Key) -> Bool
```

> Returns a `Bool` value indicating whether the decoder contains a value associated with the given key. The value associated with the given key may be a null value as appropriate for the data format.

For instance, to check if the `"age"` key exists *before* requesting the corresponding nested container:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let firstName, lastName: String
    let age: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "firstname"
        case lastName = "lastname"
        case age
    }

    enum AgeKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case realAge = "realage"
        case fakeAge = "fakeage"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)

        if values.contains(.age) {
            let age = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AgeKeys.self, forKey: .age)
            self.age = try age.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .realAge)
        } else {
            self.age = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution without the intiailizers?

Comment: @ShreeshaKedlaya The only ways without `init(from:)` is to either use nested structs, like in other answers, or use a library such as [dgrzeszczak/KeyedCodable](https://github.com/dgrzeszczak/KeyedCodable).

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue and I found this solution, just in case is helpful to somebody else:

```
let ageContainer = try? values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AgeKeys.self, forKey: .age)
self.age = try ageContainer?.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .realAge)
```

If you have an optional container, using `try? values.nestedContainer(keyedBy:forKey)` you don't need to check if the container exist using `contains(`.

Comment: needed this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try pasting your sample JSON into [quicktype](https://quicktype.io?l=swift) to see what types it infers? Based on your question, I pasted your samples and got:

```swift
struct UserInfo: Codable {
    let firstname: String
    let age: Age?
    let lastname: String
}

struct Age: Codable {
    let realage: Int?
}
```

Making `UserInfo.age` and `Age.realage` optionals works, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this with 1 class/struct. I have specific reasons for designing it with 1 class/struct. See my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737735/894067) for more info.

Comment: Ah, I see – I have to agree with the answer there that suggests a 'raw' model corresponding to the JSON structure, which you could map to your higher-level model with the idiosyncratic behavior you desire! I think this could be much easier to maintain and understand than implementing custom decoders, but good luck either way!

Comment: Just the way my data is structured in my server files and such makes it a lot easier to use custom decoders. And just from my understanding and structuring it's a lot easier to do it this way. Maybe someone will be able to give an answer that fits what I want. Thanks for your help tho.