# Nested Container nil value custom decoder Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, networking, decoding

So I have this simple json response:

```
{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad",
        "last": "gibson"
        }
}
```

And this is my customer decoder:

```
struct UserModel: Decodable {
    var gender: String
    var title: String?
    var first: String?
    var last: String?
    
    // Top-level coding keys
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, gender
    }
    
    enum NameKeys: CodingKey {
        case title, first, last
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        gender = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .gender)
        let name = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: NameKeys.self, forKey: .name)
        title = try name.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        first = try name.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .first)
        last = try name.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .last)
    }
}
```

I know how to handle the error scenarios if one of the keys inside the nested object name (*title, first, last*) isn't sent. My question is how would I write something to prevent a crash if the "name" object is not sent back from the response?

Comment: Create a nested `Codable` type. Which parameters do you require, just `gender`?

Comment: yeah so for example, say for some reason "name" does't get sent in the response and it's just gender that's returned, it crashes.

Comment: Should a name _always_ contain `title`, `first`, and `last`? Currently it just defaults them to empty strings rather than `nil`

Comment: updated so that they are nil @George

Comment: Btw `?? nil` is redundant

Answer (score 2):

You can have nested `Codable` structs, as such:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let gender: String
    let name: UserName?
}

struct UserName: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let first: String?
    let last: String?
}
```

To make the syntax better than `user.name?.title`, we can change this to just `user.title` with the use of `@dynamicMemberLookup`. Change `User` to this:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct User: Codable {
    let gender: String
    let name: UserName?

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember k: KeyPath<UserName, T>) -> T? {
        name?[keyPath: k]
    }

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember k: KeyPath<UserName, T?>) -> T? {
        name?[keyPath: k]
    }
}
```

Now, you can do the short-hand form to get each property. This now mimics your single container with all the properties.

Comment: that's a cool trick. Didn't know about dynamicMemberLookup thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Deepika, this is the solution:

```
struct UserModel: Decodable {
var gender: String
var title: String?
var first: String?
var last: String?

// Top-level coding keys
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, gender
}

enum NameKeys: CodingKey {
    case title, first, last
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    gender = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .gender)
    
    if container.contains(.name) {
        let name = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: NameKeys.self, forKey: .name)
        title = try name.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        first = try name.decode(String.self, forKey: .first)
        last = try name.decode(String.self, forKey: .last)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about using below?

```
struct Name: Decodable {

    var title: String?
    var first: String?
    var last: String?

}

struct UserModel: Decodable {
    var name: Name?
    var gender: String
}
```

Then everything else gets taken care of itself. For e.g all of below will be parsed without issues.

```
{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad",
        "last": "gibson"
        }
}

{
    "gender": "male"
}

{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad"
        }
}
```

I tested using below

```
let str = """
    {
        "gender": "male",
        "name": {
            "title": "mr",
            "first": "brad"
            }
    }
    """

let usermodel = try! JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(usermodel)
```

Comment: yeah this works and was my initial solution, was just playing around with writing nested container in a custom decoder.

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740160/swift-decodable-optional-key